# Rails form validations not calling method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a simple validation form class in rails, and I can't for the life of me figure out why it isn't calling a helper method I have.  Here is the whole class:

```
class SignUpForm

  model_fields :month, :day, :year 

  validates_presence_of :month, :day, :year
  validate :validate_sign_up_date

  def validate_sign_up_date
    byebug
    puts "here"
    message = "Please enter a valid date."
    errors.add :sign_up_date, message unless Date.valid_date?(year, month, day)
  end
end
```

I call the class like `SignUpForm.new( {year: 2021, month: 3, day: 25 })`

The print statement and breakpoint never get triggered.  I'm sure it is something simple, I just can't figure out what it is.

Comment: How do you pass data to that class?

Comment: Good question, I'll edit with that @spickermann

Comment: As currently written, `SignUpForm` is a plain ruby object. Did you mean for it to `include ActiveModel::Model`?

Comment: Instantiating an object does not trigger a validation process. Have you tried `sign_up_form.valid?` where `sign_up_form = SignUpForm.new({ year: 2021, month: 3, day: 25 })`

Comment: @3limin4t0r ah, that did the trick.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `SignUpForm` is a Ruby on Rails model. The reason that the code is not triggered is pretty simple.

```
sign_up_form = SignUpForm.new(year: 2021, month: 3, day: 25)
```

Instantiates a new object. However instantiating an object does not automatically trigger the validations. To trigger these you have to call [`valid?`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations.html#method-i-valid-3F), [`invalid?`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations.html#method-i-invalid-3F), [`validate`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations.html#method-i-validate) or [`validate!`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations.html#method-i-validate-21) (the last one raises an exception).

```
sign_up_form.valid?
```

Should return `true`/`false` and set the respective errors if `false` is returned. These are available through `sign_up_form.errors`.

If your class is a full on Ruby on Rails model `save`, `update`, etc. will call one of the above methods to ensure that the instance is valid before sending the data to the database. You should be aware that [there are some methods that skip the validations](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#skipping-callbacks).